# Create a chart for SharePoint 2010 Webpart

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I've created a connection from my webpart to an Oracle database, that contains dates and numbers.

I want to display this data in a chart.

I've looked on the internet for any examples, but I'm stumped.

Can anyone point me to some simple instructions that detail how to create a chart in c sharp that will work on a webpart, please??

Cheers

Comment: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart  Click on the downloads tab and download the asp.net sample solution.  The mschart controls will work with SharePoint web parts because they are simply rendered as images.

Answer (score 0):

basically the Webpart end in normal html,css and JavaScript. So you could use any js library to create the Chart. (For example: [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)

You can override the RenderWebPart() Method, to generate custom HTML. This way you can create the  element and a custom  element that contains var data = {} that can be plottet with charts.js

Regards