# Sharepoint 2010 create diagram programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, diagram

I try to find out how diagrams can be created in SharePoint 2010 programmatically. 
I have sharepoint-lists with different data and this data should be analysed with help of diagrams. 
I havent not found a lot information in google about it. I have seen a solution with Google Charts (http://blog.vgrem.com/2012/05/14/visualizing-organizational-charts-in-sharepoint-with-googe-chart-tools/) but I want to know, whether SharePoint can it out of the box.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Sorry for my english. I do my best. :)

Update: 
Hier is the same or similar question [Create a chart for SharePoint 2010 Webpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091502/create-a-chart-for-sharepoint-2010-webpart)

Comment: Do what out of the box? Create a static png, visio diagram, some other format (no, use any library you like)? Or bind the data and render an existing Visio diagram (yes)?

Comment: I dont know exact. I am newby in SharePoint-development. It is not realy important what for format will be used. 
It can be a static image. It's a good idea! I can use extern library/framework to generate it. Maybe you can recommend one?
I have no experience in using Visio... Maybe this solution can be good. 
What is the simpliest way?

Comment: I think, I have found what I need: http://www.dynamics101.com/2013/03/chart-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010/ 
But I have not an Enterprise-version of SharePoint and I can not use it... ><

Comment: For developer who have not enterprise-version of SharePoint can use ASP.NET-Charts. Good example is hier available: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418 This mschart controls should work fine in SharePoint.